# Command line for-loop in powershell

Tags: powershell, command-line

Suppose I have list {string1, string2, ..., stringN}. N is greater than 50.

Now I have a command line query which takes one string, I want to execute this command over and over with its string argument assuming each of the string values in my list. How to do this?

Am on windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ForEach` construct:

```
ForEach($x in $y) {
    (your commands on $x)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the `foreach` statement is the `foreach-object` commandlet:

```
$list | foreach-object { do-something-with $_ }
```

If you are generating your list from a command, `foreach-object` might be better because it will execute your command as the list is generated. If your list is already created, `foreach` might be better because it can optimize the execution of the loop body.